# Can't implement Pause functionality for CountDownTimer in listener class

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I am trying to use a CountDownTimer in a listener class - I'm running into problems with trying to get the Pause functionality working - please refer to my code below. I've added in comments the two lines I am getting errors at compile time.

```
        public void StartOrStopTimer(){
            if (TimerAlreadyRunning == false){
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                new CountDownTimer(180000, 1000) {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        TimerText.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                    }
                    public void onFinish() {
                        TimerText.setText("done!");
                    }
                }.start();
                TimerAlreadyRunning=true;             
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Stop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                TimerPauseTime = CountDownTimer.millisUntilFinished; //THIS LINE DOESNT WORK - CANT RESOLVE SYMBOL
                CountDownTimer.cancel();/// XXX THIS IS THE ERROR - CAN NOT BE REFERENCED FROM STATIC CONTENT
                TimerAlreadyRunning=false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

millisUntilFinished - is a method parameter that is accessible only in onTick, it cannot be used outside this method.

cancel() must be invoked on a class instance, you are trying to use it as a static method, but it's not static. You should add new field of type CountDownTimer to your class (like TimerAlreadyRunning variable), initialize it with new CountDownTimer(180000, 1000), and then invoke cancel method on this field...

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ayzen - I'm still starting out with Java and am having trouble with the code to implement your suggestion. Do I need to build a separate class for the CountDownTimer ?

Comment: No, you need to add and use a field of CountDownTimer type in your current class: private CountDownTimer mTimer;

Comment: Ok - but how do I then create the I'm trying the following with noluck:              mTimer.new(CountDownTimer(180,100).start());

Comment: You have to enhance your Java knowledge in order to develop for Android without pain. :) mTimer = new CountDownTimer(180000, 1000) { ... }; mTimer.start();